# Displaying 3rd party FeatureSet geometries on jupyter notebook webmap using ArcGIS Python API

Tags: python, arcgis-python-api

**How can I add all geometries included in a FeatureSet to a web map?**

Trying to add geometries (i.e., shapes) to a Jupyter notebook web map (see code sample below).

Adding features from the ArcGIS server is a breeze. But what about adding from third parties?

My geometries are first imported as a `.geojson`, which I convert to an `arcgis.feature.FeatureSet`.

For each feature in the set, I'd like to use the coordinates of each shape to add that shape to a web map.

Setup: latest anaconda python with arcgis API v.1.4 on a Linux 16.04 box.

```
import arcgis
from IPython.display import display
import requests

# link build
HI_geo_stem = 'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/'
HI_parcels_json = '1eb5fa03038d49cba930096ea67194e0_5'
parcels_link = ''.join([HI_geo_stem, HI_parcels_json, '.geojson'])

# read in parcel json
raw_parcels_json = requests.get(parcels_link).json()

# convert json to arcgis FeatureSet
hi_arc_parcels = arcgis.features.FeatureSet.from_geojson(raw_parcels_json)

# display a web mapgis = arcgis.GIS("https://www.arcgis.com")
m = gis.map("Hawaii", zoomlevel = 10)‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

# now display hi_arc_parcels in web map m‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍ ??
```

Answer (score 2):

So with quite a bit more digging around in the sample notebooks provided by ESRI, I found the `map.draw` method. It can take both `features` and `featuresets` and draw their shapes onto a web map. The only problem is that with large featuresets (>100k in my case ), the browser can take a long time to output and you'll get messages asking you to kill the running script.